# Detecting a constexpr size() member function in C++ 14

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming, constexpr

I have some generic code that would like to know when it has been passed a sequence of objects the number of which is known at compile time, as then it can choose an alternative algorithmic strategy. To that end I've tried writing a `has_constexpr_size(T)` constexpr function as below which attempts to probe T's `size()` member function to see if it can be executed as constexpr.

Note there is a key difference here from the usual "Can I detect a constexpr execution context?" questions because some STL containers like `array<T>` *always* provide a constexpr-available `size()` function whereas other STL containers like `initializer_list<T>` gain a constexpr-available `size()` function if and only if the initializer list is itself constexpr (because the implementation depends on the internal pointer pair, and those need to be constexpr for the `size()` to have all-constexpr inputs). The `has_constexpr_size(T)` function therefore takes an instance of the type `T` being tested in order that it can detect both situations.

Here is a testcase:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

namespace type_traits
{
  namespace detail
  {
    template <size_t N> struct Char
    {
      char foo[N];
    };
    template <class T> constexpr inline Char<2> constexpr_size(T &&v) { return (v.size(), true) ? Char<2>() : throw 0; }
    template <class T> inline Char<1> constexpr_size(...) { return Char<1>(); }
  }
  //! Returns true if the instance of v has a constexpr size()
  template <class T> constexpr inline bool has_constexpr_size(T &&v)
  {
    return noexcept(detail::constexpr_size<T>(std::forward<T>(v)));
  }

  // Non-constexpr array (always has a constexpr size())
  auto ca=std::array<int, 2>();
  // Constexpr initializer_list (has constexpr size()). Note fails to compile on VS2015 as its initializer_list isn't constexpr capable yet
  constexpr std::initializer_list<int> cil{1, 2};
  // Non-constexpr initializer_list (does not have constexpr size())
  std::initializer_list<int> il{1, 2};
  // Non-constexpr vector (never has constexpr size())
  std::vector<int> vec{1, 2};

  // Passes on GCC 4.9 and clang 3.8
  static_assert(ca.size(), "non-constexpr array size constexpr");
  // Passes on GCC 4.9 and clang 3.8
  static_assert(cil.size(), "constexpr il size constexpr");
  // Fails as you'd expect everywhere with non-constexpr il error
  //static_assert(il.size(), "non-constexpr il size constexpr");

  // Passes on GCC 4.9, fails on VS2015 and clang 3.8
  static_assert(has_constexpr_size(ca), "ca");  // Should NOT fail on VS2015 and clang 3.8
  // Fails on GCC 4.9 and clang 3.8. VS2015 doesn't apply.
  static_assert(has_constexpr_size(cil), "cil");  // FAILS, and it should not!
  // Passes, correct
  static_assert(!has_constexpr_size(il), "il");
  // Passes, correct
  static_assert(!has_constexpr_size(vec), "vec");

  constexpr bool test()
  {
    return has_constexpr_size(std::initializer_list<int>{1, 2});
  }
  constexpr bool testval=test();
  // Fails on GCC 4.9 and clang 3.8. VS2015 doesn't apply.
  static_assert(testval, "test()");
}
```

You'll note the direct static assertion of `array<T>::size()` and constexpr `initializer_list<T>::size()` works fine on all compilers, as you'd expect. My `has_constexpr_size(T)` function works fine for `array<T>`, but only on GCC 4.9 which I assume is because of GCC's particularly tolerant constexpr implementation. My `has_constexpr_size(T)` function fails for constexpr `initializer_list<T>` on all compilers.

So my questions are:

1. Can a `has_constexpr_size(T)` function be written which correctly detects a constexpr-available `size()` member function for `array<T>` and constexpr `initializer_list<T>` and any other type providing a constexpr-available `size()` function?
2. If (1) is not possible currently in C++ or in current compilers, can a `has_constexpr_size(T)` function be written which correctly detects a constexpr-available `size()` member function for `array<T>` and any other type providing an always constexpr-available `size()` function? **Note** this solution is not checking for whether simply some `size()` function exists, rather if it is constexpr-available. So `has_constexpr_size(std::vector<int>())` would be false.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** The below answer is unfortunately **wrong**, if you substitute `std::string` as the type instead of `int` e.g. `std::array<std::string, 2>` you'll find it fails. For some reason which makes no sense to me, C++ 14 treats the following as this:

```
  static_assert(static_cast<std::array<int, 2> *>(0)->size(), "foo");          // passes
  static_assert(static_cast<std::array<std::string, 2> *>(0)->size(), "foo");  // fails
```

I am officially dumbfounded. Anyway, I'll leave the answer below for historical interest.

---

I have a working solution for my own question 2 where using Expression SFINAE I can detect a non-zero constexpr-available `size()` member function for `array<>` and correctly exclude that for `vector<>`, but it gets constexpr `initializer_list<>` wrong. Confirmed working on GCC 4.9 and clang 3.8 and VS2015:

```
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

namespace type_traits {
  namespace detail {
    template <size_t N> struct Char { char foo[N]; };
    // Overload only available if a default constructed T has a constexpr-available non-zero size()
    template <class T, size_t N = T{}.size() + 1>
    constexpr inline Char<N> constexpr_size(const T &) {
      return Char<N>();
    }
    template <class T> constexpr inline Char<1> constexpr_size(...) {
      return Char<1>();
    }
  }
  //! Returns true if the instance of v has a constexpr size()
  template <class T> constexpr inline bool has_constexpr_size(const T &v) {
    return sizeof(detail::constexpr_size<typename std::decay<T>::type>(
               std::move(v))) > 1;
  }

  // Non-constexpr array (always has a constexpr size())
  auto ca = std::array<int, 2>();
  // Constexpr initializer_list (has constexpr size()). Note fails to compile on
  // VS2015 as its initializer_list isn't constexpr constructible yet
  #ifndef _MSC_VER
  constexpr std::initializer_list<int> cil{1, 2};
  #endif
  // Non-constexpr initializer_list (does not have constexpr size())
  std::initializer_list<int> il{1, 2};
  // Non-constexpr vector (never has constexpr size())
  std::vector<int> vec{1, 2};

  // Correct on GCC 4.9 and clang 3.8 and VS2015
  static_assert(ca.size(), "non-constexpr array size constexpr");
  // Correct on GCC 4.9 and clang 3.8.
  #ifndef _MSC_VER
  static_assert(cil.size(), "constexpr il size constexpr");
  #endif
  // Fails as you'd expect everywhere with non-constexpr il error
  // static_assert(il.size(), "non-constexpr il size constexpr");

  // Correct on GCC 4.9 and clang 3.8 and VS2015
  static_assert(has_constexpr_size(ca), "ca");
  // Incorrect on GCC 4.9 and clang 3.8 and VS2015
  #ifndef _MSC_VER
  static_assert(!has_constexpr_size(cil), "cil");  // INCORRECT!
  #endif
  // Correct on GCC 4.9 and clang 3.8 and VS2015
  static_assert(!has_constexpr_size(il), "il");
  // Correct on GCC 4.9 and clang 3.8 and VS2015
  static_assert(!has_constexpr_size(vec), "vec");

  constexpr bool test_ca() {
    return has_constexpr_size(std::array<int, 2>{1, 2});
  }
  constexpr bool testca = test_ca();
  // Correct on GCC 4.9 and clang 3.8 and VS2015
  static_assert(testca, "testca()");

  constexpr bool test_cil() {
    return has_constexpr_size(std::initializer_list<int>{1, 2});
  }
  constexpr bool testcil = test_cil();
  // Incorrect on GCC 4.9 and clang 3.8 and VS2015
  static_assert(!testcil, "testcil()");          // INCORRECT!
}
```

So all we need now is some method of filtering out non-constexpr input types so we can correctly return false for non-constexpr input. I suspect this is the same unsolved problem as elsewhere on stackoverflow :(

Any further advancement, or thoughts, is very welcome.

Comment: Are there cases where remove_cv after decay is not redundant?

Comment: I thought decay doesn't always remove cv qualifiers. Checking ... http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay says cv is only removed if the type is not an array and not a function pointer. I agree above it's probably redundant, but I was making very sure the routine only ever sees non-const non-volatile types to avoid surprises.

Comment: @MarcGlisse I've improved the answer, removing the remove_cv.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm interpreting this proposal:

[std::is_constant_evaluated()](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0595r1.html)

correctly, the standard's wording as of C++14 does not even clarify what must be known at compile time and what doesn't. And, at any rate, this "magical library function", added in C++20, could not be implemented in the language itself.

The GCC 9 implementation is:

```
constexpr inline bool
is_constant_evaluated() noexcept
{ return __builtin_is_constant_evaluated(); }
```

which is another indication (although not a certain one) that this can't be implemented using other language constructs.